# Apache Storm architecture - is this the right way to go?

Tags: architecture, apache-storm

I need to create a topology which will simulate N identical processing nodes, each processing a stream, communicating with a coordinator node. Communication (two way) is allowed only between a processing node and the coordinator node.

I was thinking of the following architecture: the processing nodes will be implemented in Storm. The coordinator will have a web server (e.g. [Spark](http://www.sparkjava.com/)) and listen to incoming messages from the processing nodes. The messages to the coordinator will use HTTP. The coordinator will pass messages to the processing nodes by publishing them to a Kafka queue which they will subscribe to (an alternative would be to have all messages passed through the queue).

Is this a good way to go? Do you have better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your case and environment, I don't really know if this is the best approach or not. Personally, I didn't like the HTTP part (Storm bolt submitting events to servlet).

I would use Kafka also to send events from Storm bolts. This way, you will have a unified approach for communication and most likely, a non-blocking one.

And you need to think what happens if the tuple is replayed (in case you are employing this feature).

*Spark in your question is a web framework, not a web server.*